# Creating GUIs for application

Tags: c++, eclipse, user-interface

This is a question I've been wondering about for a long time.
How do you create an Interface for your program ?
It seems to much of a pain to position form controls and buttons using just code.
I'm looking for something similar to Visual Basic where you can drag and drop controls onto the window. But, I want to do this for applications written in C++.
Can It be done with compilers like MinGW on Eclipse ?

Comment: Eclipse is not a compiler just an IDE. I'd really recommend Qt with QtCreator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go the Qt route you can use [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) which is freeware. It will produce Win32 friendly .rc files that can be built with the MinGW resource compiler and used in Win32 applications.

There are some C++ Win32 wrapper libraries available though I'm not aware of any that are nearly as mature as Qt. I believe [WinxGui](http://code.google.com/p/winx/) is a port of [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/) (or at least claims to be compatible with WTL) for GCC. It doesn't look like there has been much activity on the project site for a few years however.

Comment: What im mail looking for is something that has a graphical front end for building the GUI. And of course, compiler integration would be great too.
How would I add the .rc files to the compiler ?

Comment: ResEdit is a drag-and-drop GUI builder. It is probably the best GUI builder I've seen outside Microsoft's Visual Studio. Unfortunately it is a stand alone application (No IDE integration). You build the resource (.rc file) using winres.exe which comes with MinGW. It will output an object file (.o) file which you link into your application with all your other object files.

Comment: Downloaded ResEdit, and it IS what I was looking for :)
Once I conver the .rc file to a .o file, I have to link to it in my IDE, right ?
And, how will i write code for the various form elements ?

Comment: What libraries do I need to link to compile a Win32 App using MinGW ?
Im getting errors like `Function 'DialogBoxParamA' could not be resolved`

Comment: I'd start by making sure you are using the `-mwindows` switch for example: `gcc -o foo.exe foo.o resources.o -mwindows` If that does not work you should start a new question posting some code, the command you are executing and the errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

What you're searching for is called [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), both [Eclipse](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration/) and [MinGW](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp) friendly.
Check out [this nice article](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2007/07/11/develop-qt-applications-in-eclipse/).

Comment: I downloaded and installed the Eclipse plugin, but I'm unable to create a Qt Project!

Comment: Also, Qt seems to be a 1.7GB download. What about wxwidgets, or WPF ? Do they have builders like Qt ?

Comment: If you'll follow the MinGW link I've provided, there is limited Qt version (320Mb) without Qt Creator, and some other tools. It should include everything you would need for Qt development on Eclipse/MinGW. There is well documented installation how-to: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-eclipse-1.6/eclipse-integration-installation.html

Comment: I was working with most of the available cross-platform GUI toolkits out there, but IMHO, Qt is the best one. There is no nice GUI builders  for other toolkits, incl. WxWidgets (one reasonable form builder exists so far - http://wxformbuilder.org, others not really recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Qt toolkit is written in C++. So you can use it to develop GUI. It also comes with Qt Designer and Qt Creator IDE and tools.

- [Qt Reference Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/index.html)
- [Qt Designer Manual](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-manual.html)
- [Qt Creator IDE and tools](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/)

And you can use MinGW to compile the code. You don't need to download MInGW separately. When [installing Qt toolkik](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads), it asks if you want to download MInGW also, just say **yes** to it. It will then download the correct version of MInGW itself.

Answer (score 1):

The 1.7 GB download you look at is probably the full Qt SDK. This is not just Qt and documentation, but also includes the Qt Creator IDE with the Qt Designer "Form builder", the MinGW compiler, debugger, examples, demos, and some other stuff. There's also an "online installer" that allows you to select the packages you want before downloading everything. That's probably what I'd use if I were starting from scratch on Windows.